# What type of hose connector will fit my kitchen tap?

Tags: hoses, water

I am trying to connect my garden hose to my [kitchen tap](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Toba-Mono-Mixer-Kitchen-Sink-Tap-Chrome/p/207006) which looks like this.

[image]

I foolishly bought http://www.hozelock.com/watering/hose-fittings/connect-to-tap/2177---indoor-round-tap-connector.html but the bevel on my tap stops the connector from holding on properly.

[image]

What sort of connector can I buy that will give a reliable connection?

Comment: the bevel part looks like the aerator. Unscrew it and see if the thing you bought will then fit.

Answer (score 3):

It look like you have a similar tap to ours but you cannot be sure until you take off the aerator and see what size of thread is used and whether the thread is on the outside of the tap or the inside.  If the thread holding the aerator is on the outside like ours then most hardware stores will be happy to sell you a ring with kitchen tap thread on the top and outside hose thread on the bottom.

Inside threaded adaptor
[image: Inside Thread adaptor]

Don't be fooled like I was and consider the flat washer between the ring and the tap to be optional..

Comment: But it *is* optional, if you don't mind water all over your kitchen.